# Is there a way to map objects to primitives?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, dictionary, primitive

This may be a hypothetical question, I'm not sure.

Coming from a C# background, I've always missed object-oriented primitives in Objective-C. Instead, you have to endlessly convert from `BOOL` and `int` to `NSNumber` and back again, creating unwieldy and potentially buggy code.

Is it technically possible to globally map all the primitive value types, such as `int`, `BOOL`, `float`, etc., to their object-oriented counter-pieces, i.e. `NSNumber`?

Comment: What do you mean “you have to endlessly convert from [primitive types] to NSNumber and back again”? I seldom have to do this in my apps; sometimes I do, but it's rare. Why are you converting?

Comment: Core Data. You can't store primitive values in a persistent model, and rightfully so. I just wish Cocoa's primitives were actual objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically possible?  Sure.  Totally.

See `CF*Dictionary` and/or `NSMapTable`.  Both allow mappings between Objective-C instances and primitive and/or non-Objective-C types.

You'd obviously have to write some code to do the lookups, as needed, (or modify the compiler to do it for you.   Overall, probably not worth doing so as it'll be complex and offer more moving parts to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, nor do I think it would do you much good. Best to just go with the flow. If you don't ignore compiler warnings this should rarely result in buggy code.